# SQL Contains query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables (A and B) that contain ID's however in table B some records have these ID's grouped together e.g the IDExec column may consist of a record that looks like 'id1 id2'. I'm trying to find the ID's in table A that do not appear in table B. I thought that by using something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM A 
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT * 
                  FROM  B 
                  WHERE Contains(A.ExecID, B.ExecID))
```

This isn't working as contains needs the 2nd parameter to be string, text_lex or variable.

Do you guys have a solution to this problem?

To shed more light on the above problem the table strucutres are as follows:

```
Table A (IDExec, ProdName, BuySell, Quantity, Price, DateTime)  
Table B (IDExec, ClientAccountNo, Quantity)
```

The C# code I've created to manipulate the buysell data in Table A groups up all the buysell's of the same product on a given day. The question now is how would you guy normalise this so I'm not bastardizing IDExec? Would it be better to create a new ID column in Table B called AllocID and link the two tables like that? So something like this:

```
Table A (IDExec, AllocID, ProdName, BuySell, Quantity, Price, DateTime)  
Table B (AllocID, ClientAccountNo, Quantity)
```

Comment: Hi  juergen d sorry new to this. It's MS Sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This data should be normalized, storing multiple values in one field is a bad idea.

A workaround is using `LIKE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM A 
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT * 
                  FROM  B 
                  WHERE ' '+B.ExecID+' ' LIKE '% '+A.ExecID+' %')
```

This is using space delimited values per your example.

Comment: Thanks Goat CO. I agree this should be normalized and maybe you can give your opinon on how this should be done. Table A contains purchases and sales, i've written a programme which manipulates that data to produce breakdowns. For optimization purposes im grouping together all the purchases and sales which are the same product and price. This is why in table B the ID's are grouped together. I'm sure theres a better way to do this i'm just not smart enough.

Comment: It depends a bit, you could simply make multiple records from each record that currently has multiple ID's listed.  If doing that results in massive redundancy, then additional tables may be warranted. Databases are designed to handle many rows, but multiple values in a single field will always perform poorly. If you add to your question your current table structure and a brief description of the relationship between `A` and `B` we can likely suggest how to best normalize this.

Comment: Thanks Goat CO will do.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of crude, but it will give you all of the entries in `A` that are not contained in `B`.

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE A.ExecID not in (SELECT ExecID from B);
```

Comment: This could be incredibly inefficient if B is a large table, consider using a left join and a check against null if the table is large since the index collision will add logaritmic overhead, rather than linear(and although slightly slower for 50 rows it'll be much faster for 50,000).

Comment: Thanks for your comments dave and scargar. These tables are storing a vast amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

I have a very simple solution. It's called normalization. Proper modeling can work wonders for query simplicity and accuracy.

However, you may be stuck with what you have. Assuming `ExecID` is a string in both tables, try this:

```
select  *
from    A
where not exists(
    select  *
    from    B
    where   ExecID like '%' || a.ExecID || '%';
```

This is a horrible query as it performs a complete table scan of B for every row in A and the subquery is susceptible to false hits, so maybe you can do better, but your best course ultimately is a touch of database refactoring.

Comment: This is invalid syntax for SQL Server.

Comment: Yes, I happen to be wearing my Oracle hat at the moment but I didn't intend for the code to actually be adopted. `For illustration only. Do not try this at work!`